# Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 generate Release build Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResource'

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, release-builds

I won't able to generate release build in android studio 3.0 Beta 2,

Execution failed with below error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> java.io.IOException: Internal error: Symbol file with package cannot be empty.

Comment: For temporary solution if you want urgent You can degrade/decrease the Android Studio Version.

Example --> Android Studio Version 3.0 Beta  to 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved in Android studio beta-4

Just update your android studio and related build script.